# Google Sheets ROUNDDOWN formula doesn't work in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

This is a formula I'm using in a Gantt/time-line chart to drive different values to a cell:

```
=if(AND((K$3>=$G8),(K$3<=$H8)),if((ROUNDDOWN($J8*$I8)<=(K$3-$G8)), "X", "Y"),"")
```

It works fine in Google Sheets, but when pasted into Excel, it throws an error that says "Not enough arguments were entered for this function."

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: `=if(AND((K$3>=$G8),(K$3<=$H8)),if((ROUNDDOWN($J8*$I8, 0)<=(K$3-$G8)), "X", "Y"),"")` You need a rounding figure (aka *significance*) for ROUNDDOWN. The above rounds to whole numbers.

Answer (score 3):

your roundown part is missing an argument. try this `=IF(AND((K$3>=$G8),(K$3<=$H8)),IF((ROUNDDOWN($J8*$I8,0)<=(K$3-$G8)),"X","Y"),"")`

Comment: May be appropriate to note that [tag:google-sheets] **defaults** the ROUNDDOWN to **0** or whole numbers while [tag:excel] does not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to just add a comma after J8*I8, and that seemed to solve the issue. Excel required a digit there for some reason.

Comment: the some reason is to define what degree of accuracy you want to round to? .1 would be ,1, .001 would be ,3, 100 would be ,-2.  Reading Jeeped's  comments states the difference between excel and google sheets.